# How to close a browser window programatically in Windows using Java

Tags: java, selenium, awt

I am writing a program to search a word meaning in internet. It will read the words from a file, open the default browser, search the word in google, take a snapshot of it & save it somewhere.

Problem is when I search programatically say for 25 words, 25 tabs open in the browser. So the computer becomes slow. To solve it I want to close the browser after searching 10 words. Is there any way to close it programatically. I am using java.awt. OS is Windows 8. Here is the function that I call in a loop for searching a word.

```
public static void takeSnapshot(String word, String folderLocation) {

        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {// For windows
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q="
                          + word + "%20meaning"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /* For linux
         * Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); try { runtime.exec(
         * "/usr/bin/google-chrome -new-window " +
         * "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q="
         * + word + "%20meaning"); } catch (IOException e1) { // TODO
         * Auto-generated catch block e1.printStackTrace(); }
         */

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle();
        screenRect.setBounds(100, 150, 700, 700);
        BufferedImage capture;
        try {
            capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            ImageIO.write(capture, "bmp", new File(folderLocation, word + ".bmp"));
            System.out.println("Image is written");
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't open and manipulate the browser using selenium ? It's unclear how you open it .

Comment: @PascalHeraud `Desktop.getDesktop().browse`

Comment: While you can do what you want, it's inherently dangerous, as you don't "really" know which process you're dealing with, was the browser opened by you or by the user, for example.  You will need to investigate JNI/JNA, what you're trying to do is find the window which was opened by `Desktop`, now because this just uses what ever default the OS has setup, this becomes an issue.  My "general" advice would be to list the windows before you use `Desktop`, then list the windows after it (or a short while after it) and "hope" you can find the right window